# Envoy (service mesh) running as a Docker container

Tags: docker, envoyproxy

We want to do some testing on envoy, and we have a Docker container pulled from DockerHub  envoyproxy/envoy running under Docker.  However if one opens a CLI into the container there is no file called envoy, and if we look at a browser for http://localhost:443 nothing happens.  Is envoy actually running in the container?  ps shows the only running processes are bash and the ps command.  So how do you test an envoy config file in the container, for example html.yaml?

We can run envoy standalone with a config file, but that is not the environment we will be using.

The Envoy Documentation is very long and very thorough, but to us at least this isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily test Envoy inside a Docker container by running:

```
docker run --name envoy \
    -p 443:443 \
    -v $PWD/html.yaml:/etc/envoy/envoy.yaml \
    envoyproxy/envoy:v1.21.1
```

You must bind mount your config into `/etc/envoy/envoy.yaml` in the container.

Note that in order to access your services, you may want to run envoy in host network (`--net=host`), or at least in the same network as your services.

Also, the entrypoint command can be seen by executing `ps -ef`:

```
$ docker exec envoy ps -ef
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
envoy          1       0  1 16:47 pts/0    00:00:01 envoy -c /etc/envoy/envoy.yaml
```